# Why are ethernet connections disappearing from new laptops?

Tags: wifi, networking, ethernet, performance

When looking to purchase a laptop, I am finding it difficult to find one with the specification I prefer **and** an ethernet connection.

When, for example, uploading a pre-built website to a hosting server, a decent connection speed is preferred as it can take a while on WiFi. Ethernet is far faster than WiFi speeds.

Is there a reason ethernet connections are not being provided on many laptops now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably fake answer that laptop manufacturers are gonna give you: yes, we need to make laptops thinner and ethernet ports are too big.

Probably real answer: Cost saving. Good network controllers can cost like €40 and spending money on 2 is not really that cost effective. So they only spend money on the one most peoples prefer using, which is wifi. It's not because they are too big (both HP and Framework have used/are using smaller ethernet ports that extend to a full size when you plug the cable in), but the main reason is probably cost savings